# org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/MUIElement Class Not Found , Java Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am doing a CIMTool project, for a handle of WorkbenchWindow

## Code Snippet

```
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
//(both these Classes are present in Libraries)
IWorkbenchWindow window=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
```

## Issues

Following Error is slapped

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/MUIElement
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:90)*

## Environment

Eclipse : Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Juno Service Release 2 
OS      : MS Windows 7 Professional, X86
Java Version : java version "1.7.0_25"

## Questions

- I tried searching for org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/*, I could not find in
  Archives. Where I can find ?
- Is there any otherway to get IWorkbenchWindow Instance ? (want to
  avoid this issue)

This problem I found that, doesnt appear in Java Indigo. But my project has to be developed in Eclipse , so I cant migrate.

thanks

Comment: Is this in an Eclipse plugin or headless application? You can only use `IWorkbenchWindow` in a plugin (or headless app), it will not work in an ordinary Java program.

Answer (score 0):

I also was confronted with this error when executing code from within a project that was created as "SWT/JFace Java Project" using Eclipse Kepler (displaying a ListSelectionDialog).

The main problem is that the project set-up misses a JAR file that contains the MUIElement  class. You can easily fix the project set-up by editing the build-path, adding the external jar which has a name similar to this one:

**org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench_1.0.1.v20131118-1956.jar**.

You find that jar in the plugins directory of your Eclipse installation.