# NoClassDefFoundError on MUIElement class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, noclassdeffounderror

I try to convert an Eclipse RCP application 4.2 from Java 7 to Java 8 but I get the following exception. The application is built with maven and org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench is a dependance but when the running the app, a NoClassDefFoundError is thrown.

Is it possible that E4.2 and Java 8 are incompatible ?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/MUIElement
    at org.example.LifeCycleManager.initialize(LifeCycleManager.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.lambda$0(E4Application.java:239)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.MUIElement cannot be found by org.example.util_1.0.0.201710051633
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314433/org-eclipse-e4-ui-model-application-ui-muielement-class-not-found-java-eclipse

Comment: The stack trace shows Eclipse 4.7 code which **must** be run with Java 8, Most likely you need to update the list of plugins included in the RCP since it changes between 4.2 and 4.7

Comment: Where can I find the list of plugin's versions corresponding to 4.7 ?